# Using Rs fft function

Tags: r, fft

I'm currently trying to use the fft function in R to transform measured soil temperature at a certain depths so as to model soil temperatures and heat fluxes at different depths.

I wanted to clarify some points regarding the fft function in R as i'm currently experiencing problems implementing this procedure.

So I have a df containing the date and time and soil temperatures at 5cm (T5) depth for a period of several months. According to the literature, it is possible to simulate temperatures and heat fluxes at different depths based on a fast Fourier transform of the measured data.
So my first step was naturally DF$FFT = fft (DF$T5)
From which I receive a series of complex numbers (Cn) i.e. the respective real (an) and imaginary (bn) numbers.
According to the literature, I can then recreate the T5 data with a formula based on outputs from the aforementioned fft.

```
*T_(0,t )= meanT + ∑ (An sin⁡〖nωt+φ〗) ̅
```

NB the summed term is summed between n=1 and M, the highest harmonic

where T o,t is the temperature at given time point, mean Temperature over the period, t is the time and...

```
An = (2/sqrt(N))*|Cn|
|Cn| = modulus of the complex number of the nth harmonic Mod (DF$FFT)
phi = arctan (an/bn) i.e. arctan (Re(DF$FFT)/Im(DF$FFT)
omega = (2*pi/N)
```

Unfortunately based on the output of the fft in R i cannot recreate the temperature values using the above formula. I realise i can recreate the data using

```
fft (fft(DF$T5), inverse = T)/length (DF$T5)
```

However i need to be able to do it with the above equation so as to use the terms from this equation to model temperatures at other depths. Could anyone lend a hand in where i may be going wrong with the procedure i have described above.  For example the above procedure was implemented in paper where the fft function from Mathcad was used! I am not looking here for a quick fix solution to my problem, so i understand that more data and info would be handy if that were the case.  What i am looking for though is a bit of guidance with e.g. any peculiarities of the R fft that i should be aware of.

If anyone could help in any way possible it would be most appreciated. Also if anyone needs more info regarding my problem please do ask

thanks a lot

Brad

Comment: Welcome to SO! Although you are not looking for a "quick fix", it would be really helpful to give some sample data, and a sample of what you want as a result. A link to the paper you are using would also be helpful. We also usually don't write "thanks" at the end of questions to keep things concise.

Comment: Hi There. The problem was in fact to do with the equation and not R's fft output